# Deprecated Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() returns different values than the new one getExternalFilesDir(null)?

Tags: java, android

Usually I used

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
```

which returns:

```
/storage/emulated/0/
```

Since its deprecated, I tried this on Activity:

```
getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath()
```

but it returns:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.music_player/files/
```

What's the correct way to return data as for Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Deprecated Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() returns different values than the new one getExternalFilesDir(null)?

Those are not equivalents; they are not supposed to return the same value.

> What's the correct way to return data as for Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()?

Your only option *is* `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()`.

You may wish to step back a bit and reconsider your problem space. You need to determine why you are trying to depend on this value and whether that is a good idea in modern Android app development.

Comment: What's the best practices for this? Basically, as source for an app, I need to point to mainroot/somefolder. at the same level where theres DCIM, Android, Download, and so on.

Comment: "Basically, as source for an app, I need to point to mainroot/somefolder. at the same level where theres DCIM, Android, Download, and so on." -- then you need to use that location. It might not *work* for what you are trying to do, due to permissions. Since I do not know what you are trying to do at a higher level, I cannot provide more specific advice.

Comment: @CommonsWave that folder on Android Studio emulator seems to be under /sdcard/. But on my smartphone where I don't have any /sdcard, I think its as /. Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() seems to point correct on both enviroment, so I need to replace it, since it is deprecated. More clear now?

Comment: @markzzz: You may not have rights to work with that directory. A safer approach is to use the Storage Access Framework (e.g., `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` / `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument`) and let the user decide where to load things from.

Comment: Ok. So let says I want to give permission to /MyApp (which is at the same level of DCIM, for example). How can I do it? /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.music_player/files/ Its unusual

Comment: @markzzz: Using filesystem APIs, there is no option for that, sorry. Using the Storage Access Framework, you could use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` / `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree` to ask the user to let you work with a document tree.

Comment: For now is ok to use the system folder. In case I'll open a vertical question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unless you go for MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE you cannot create anymore your own subdirs in root of external storage on Android 11+ devices.

Create your own subdirs in one of the public directories on external storage that are already there.

So use for instance:

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)
```

or others.

If you instead go for SAF (ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE) you still can create folders in root of external storage.

Comment: but getExternalStoragePublicDirectory its still deprecated, why should I use it?

Comment: No it is not anymore. And there is nothing else to use so dont complain. It works.

Comment: With API Level 30 it is, I see the warning